# Accessing iwd dbus interface from python

Tags: python, dbus, connman

I am trying to use python3 dbus package to control wireless on an embedded Linux target (mips MT7628, if it matters).

System is most likely set up correctly because I have iwd + dhclient up-and-running on this embedded target.

I can connect through both eth0 and wlan0.

I can also control iwd through iwctl. So far so good.

I now need to control iwd from python3; specifically I need to be able to send scan results through serial line (real target, as opposed to my development board, will be headless).

I am at a loss with dbus interface. I need some examples to start with.

I tried something along the lines:

```
# python
Python 3.8.1 (default, Feb 21 2020, 11:13:38) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dbus
>>> bus = dbus.SystemBus()
>>> wlan0 = bus.get_object('net.connman.iwd', '/net/connman/iwd/phy1/1')
>>> p = wlan0.Properties(dbus_interface='net.connman.iwd.Station')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 72, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 141, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 652, in call_blocking
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotFound: No matching method found
>>> p = wlan0.Scan(dbus_interface='net.connman.iwd.Station')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 141, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 652, in call_blocking
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotFound: No matching method found
>>>
```

This while WiFi is working:

```
# iwctl 
[iwd]# adapter list
                                    Adapters                                  *
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Name               Powered   Vendor              Model               
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  phy1               on        --

[iwd]# device list
                                    Devices                                   *
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Name                Address             Powered   Adapter   Mode      
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  wlan1               42:c1:f8:85:67:ba   on        phy1      station   

[iwd]# station list
                            Devices in Station Mode                           *
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Name                State          Scanning
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  wlan1               connected              

[iwd]#
```

... but I'm obviously missing something very basic.

Can someone point me in the right direction, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question to help whoever will stumble here:

It turns out both iwd and connman repositories come with complete python3 examples in subdirectory "test".

Adapting those to my specific needs proved trivial.

Relevant directories can be found [here (iwd)](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/wireless/iwd.git/tree/test) and [here (connman)](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/connman/connman.git/tree/test).

The solution to my specific question is in the following scripts: [scan-for-networks](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/wireless/iwd.git/tree/test/scan-for-networks) and [list-known-networks](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/wireless/iwd.git/tree/test/list-known-networks).

scan-for-networks:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import dbus


if (len(sys.argv) != 2):
    print("Usage: %s <device>" % (sys.argv[0]))
    sys.exit(1)

bus = dbus.SystemBus()
device = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object("net.connman.iwd", sys.argv[1]),
                                    "net.connman.iwd.Station")
device.Scan()
```

list_known_networks:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import dbus

bus = dbus.SystemBus()

manager = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object('net.connman.iwd', '/'),
                         'org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager')

forget = None
if len(sys.argv) >= 4 and sys.argv[1] == 'forget':
    forget = (sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3])

print('Known Networks:')

for path, interfaces in manager.GetManagedObjects().items():
    if 'net.connman.iwd.KnownNetwork' not in interfaces:
        continue

    network = interfaces['net.connman.iwd.KnownNetwork']

    if (network['Name'], network['Type']) == forget:
        obj = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object('net.connman.iwd', path),
                             'net.connman.iwd.KnownNetwork')
        obj.Forget()
        continue

    print("[ %s ]" % network['Name'])

    for key in network:
        val = network[key]
        if type(val) == dbus.Boolean:
            val = 'True' if val else 'False'
        print("    %s = %s" % (key, val))
```